# Spring MVC REST PUT is not working

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I have the following problem: Whenever I try to edit the following data, I get an exception saying that **HTTP PUT is not supported by this URL**. This is the JSP form side of things where a button is used to edit that row:

```
<c:url var="formAction" value="/circuits/${circuit.circuitId}" />
<form:form method="PUT" action="${formAction}">
    <input type="hidden" name="circuitId" value="${circuit.circuitId}" />
    <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form:form>
```

And the following is my controller method that retrieves the `circuitId`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{circuitId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public String showEditCircuitForm(@PathVariable Integer circuitId, ModelMap model) throws NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException
```

However, when I use the normal GET method everything works fine, it's just this PUT method that is causing the problem. I have got all the dependencies that I need.

Comment: remove the hidden field

Answer (score 2):

Only `get`and `post` are [officialy supported](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3) with forms. I'm not aware of any  browser that supports `put` with forms. It **is** supported with `AJAX`, though.

Apart from that the support of the Java Servlet API for `PUT` is not ideal. You might need to include a filter in your web.xml:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>httpPutFormContentFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

Before I forget: You can send a `post` request and use another filter to fake a `put` request:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

To get this working you have to include a hidden field with the name `_method` and the value `PUT` in your form.